# Validation errors not displayed after applying custom window style & template (c#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application resources I have the following style defined, well, I'm giving you the simplistic version (style is meant to be applied to all windows across the application):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}">
<Setter Property="Template">
<!--Omitting irrelevant property setters-->
<Setter.Value>
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
  <StackPanel>
   <ContentPresenter/>
  </StackPanel>
 </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

I've noticed that when this style gets applied to all windows, validation errors (IDataErrorInfo) — by means of the default red-border-box-around-control error template — aren't displayed in those windows.

What gives?

Comment: No repro.  Use Snoop to check that window and see where the AdornerLayer and AdornerDecorators are.  If you see them, the problem is elsewhere, possibly in binding, possibly in INDEI implementation.

Comment: Apoligies, my initial sample turned out to be incorrect. You mentioning AdornerDecorators made a difference though: my window style template didn't contain any, so wrapping the templated window grid into an AdornerDecorator helped to solve this. Validation errors are being displayed now. Thank you.

Comment: Boom.  You should add an answer below with details of how you solved this (your template changes would be nice) so you can close out your question.

Comment: Done. @Will, thank you again. I upvoted your hint. Can I credit you for help in any other way?

Comment: Nah, that's cool.  Wasn't sure what the issue really was, so I didn't add that as an answer.  I'm all full up on fake internet points, so no worries.

Comment: @Will, ya, OK. Marking my own answer as correct then. This is crazy, but maybe this'll make life easier for someone googling...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping the window template (StackPanel in this example) into an AdornerDecorator solved this (as the decorator is used to display validation errors).

Thanks to Will, I didn't even know what to look for.